# Configure DI containers to be available in Nextjs 14 server components (app router)

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, next.js14, awilix

I am trying to setup a dependency injection container in NextJS, which would typically require a composition root for the container to be configured at the outermost layer of my onion (i.e. index.ts). I'm using next's server components to fetch data server-side and server actions to mutate data (also on the server), so I'd like to have my DI container available in both places, but Next doesn't seem to have a concept of a single entry-point or application wrapper, from what I can tell, so I've been trying to think of a way create the DI container in one place and share it between server components and server actions.

I'm considering creating a custom server.ts file and constructing the container there. I can add it to the request context (this is what you'd typically do for request scoped containers in node/express) and I think the container will be available to server actions via the request object. BUT it seems you can't access the request object from server components in Next.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve the objective? Either by somehow sharing the request object or perhaps taking a different approach?

Thanks in advance.

server.ts:

```
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';
import { createContainer } from 'awilix';
import { scopePerRequest } from 'awilix-express';
import { configureVehicleProfileManagementContainer } from './features/vehicleProfileManagement/diContainerConfig';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

// Set up Next.js app
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

// Set up Awilix DI container
const container = createContainer({ strict: true });

//configure the vehicle profile management DI container
configureVehicleProfileManagementContainer(container);

const server = express();
server.use(scopePerRequest(container));

app.prepare().then(() => {
  // Handle all GET requests to our Next.js app
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  // Start the Express server
  server.listen(port, (err?: Error) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
  });
});
```

I've been able to use Next's inbuilt functions to get the cookies and headers from the request, but the awilix container is not available.